# How to change webview orientation in android while coming back from another screen

Tags: android, webview

I am having a screen which has a WebView showing a UI developed in HTML and PHP. Now, when i migrate to a different screen in Android and want to come back to my parent screen, I want to have a NEW WebView layout. Even though I am passing a String variable back for validating purposes, but still then it does not work out. Does this have to do anything with the savedInstanceState? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Below is the code snippet.

```
package com.example.notifboard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AdminLogin extends Activity {

boolean flag = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    flag = true;        
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (flag == true) {
        setContentView(R.layout.adminloginmixed);

        final Button AdminBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AdminBtn);
        final Button EventGenBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.EventGenBtn);
        final Button BackBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BackBtn);

        AdminBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        AdminBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);     

        EventGenBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                EventGenBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                EventGenBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                AdminBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                AdminBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                BackBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                BackBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);              
                Intent EveGenIntent = new Intent(AdminLogin.this, EventGen.class);
                startActivity(EveGenIntent);
                finish();
            }           
        });

        AdminBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                EventGenBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                EventGenBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                BackBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                BackBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);              
                AdminBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                AdminBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);             
            }
        });

        BackBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                BackBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                BackBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                EventGenBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                EventGenBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                AdminBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                AdminBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);             
                Intent BackBtnIntent = new Intent(AdminLogin.this, SelectEntryType.class);
                startActivity(BackBtnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.Adminloginwebview);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        browser.loadUrl("http://sivasphpmobileapps.site90.net/NotificationBoard/AdminLogin.php");       
    }
    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.adminloginmixed);

        final Button AdminBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AdminBtn);
        final Button EventGenBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.EventGenBtn);
        final Button BackBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BackBtn);

        AdminBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        AdminBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);     

        EventGenBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                EventGenBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                EventGenBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                AdminBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                AdminBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                BackBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                BackBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);              
                Intent EveGenIntent = new Intent(AdminLogin.this, EventGen.class);
                startActivity(EveGenIntent);                    
            }               
        });

        AdminBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                EventGenBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                EventGenBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                BackBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                BackBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);              
                AdminBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                AdminBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);                 
            }               
        });

        BackBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                BackBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                BackBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                EventGenBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                EventGenBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                AdminBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1D326B"));
                AdminBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);             
                Intent BackBtnIntent = new Intent(AdminLogin.this, SelectEntryType.class);
                startActivity(BackBtnIntent);
            }
        });

        WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.Adminloginwebview);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        browser.loadUrl("http://sivasphpmobileapps.site90.net/NotificationBoard/NewEvents.php");    
    }
}
```

}